# Ruby Mechanize: verifying a "select" element value

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize-ruby

I'm attempting to verify a value for a drop down using ruby's mechanize

I've got this pretty printed form:

Before:

```
#<Mechanize::Form
  ...
  [selectlist:0xefdae4 type:  name: time_entry[activity_id] value: []]}
  ...
 {buttons [submit:0xefe124 type: submit name: commit value: Save]}>
```

After:

```
#<Mechanize::Form
  ...
  [selectlist:0xefdae4 type:  name: time_entry[activity_id] value: []]}
  ...
 {buttons [submit:0xefe124 type: submit name: commit value: Save]}>
```

The code I'm running:

```
 @form.field_with(:name => "time_entry[activity_id]").options[2].select
```

... corresponding to the 3rd option: "Testing"

And the select HTML element:

```
<select id="time_entry_activity_id" name="time_entry[activity_id]">
  <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
  <option value="8">Design</option>
  <option value="9">Development</option>
  <option value="13">Testing</option>
  <option value="14">Dingo</option>
  <option value="15">ABPs</option>
</select>
```

I'm attempting to get some kind of verification of what item is selected from the select box.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense because I'm fighting a cold, but I see absolutely no difference between the "Before" and "After" examples, nor does `vimdiff`. Want to clear this up for us?

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect:

```
@form.field_with(:name => "time_entry[activity_id]").value
```

or maybe easier:

```
@form.values
```